# Css3 Body Animation makes Options in a select form twitch

Tags: html, css

**jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Dm7uE/

HTML:

```
<form action="delete.php" method="get">
    <label for="delete">DELETE ONE</label>
    <select name="id">
        <option value="test">test</option>
        <option value="test">test</option>
        <option value="test">test</option>
    </select>    
</form>
```

CSS

```
@-moz-keyframes pulse 
{
    0% {background-color: #45CEEF;}
    25% {background-color: #FFF5A5;}
    50% {background-color: #FFD4DA;}
    75% {background-color: #99D2E4;}
    100% {background-color: #D8CAB4;}
}
@keyframes pulse
{
    0% {background-color: #45CEEF;}
    25% {background-color: #FFF5A5;}
    50% {background-color: #FFD4DA;}
    75% {background-color: #99D2E4;}
    100% {background-color: #D8CAB4;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
    0% {background-color: #45CEEF;}
    25% {background-color: #FFF5A5;}
    50% {background-color: #FFD4DA;}
    75% {background-color: #99D2E4;}
    100% {background-color: #D8CAB4;}
}
body
{
    -webkit-animation: pulse 80s infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: pulse 80s infinite alternate;
    animation: pulse 80s infinite alternate;
    background-color: #45CEEF;
}
```

For some reason, when I have a pulsating background,it messes up my select options. If you try to hover on one of the options in the form, it just twitches back and forth .. what's causing this and how would I be able to fix it? Thank you

EDIT: If I remove the CSS, the form functions as normal.

Comment: try on webkit, that's what I'm using.

Comment: I mean nothing wrong just pulsing and I can select any option

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing around with the fiddle and looking around various sites - they all implement it the same way as you do - I guess the only other alternative would be to use JS?

Comment: how would I be able to fix it with javascript? Thanks.